# Hibernate : Fetch count is returning zero, although there is one fetch

Tags: hibernate, orm

I am trying to just get the fetch count in hibernate. The below code is very simple but still the count is displayed as zero. I am expecting '1'

```
        Employee emp = (Employee) session.load(Employee.class, 1l);
        System.out.println(emp.getName()); // Displays employee name

        System.out.println("DB Fetch Count : "+sessionFactory.getStatistics().getEntityFetchCount());//Displays '0'!
```

Comment: see differences between session.get() & session.load()  more info https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/

Comment: Hi, I suspected the same and I tried with 'get' as well, same result.

Comment: Hi i found solution on this we have to use current session for this, see my ans

Answer (score 0):

Caching is facility provided by ORM frameworks which help users to get fast running web application, while help framework itself to reduce the number of queries made to database in a single transaction. Hibernate also provide this caching functionality, in two layers.

1) **Fist level cache**: This is enabled by default and works in session scope.

2) **Second level cache**: This is apart from first level cache which is available to be used globally in the session factory scope.

So in your case you are using the first-level cache, this cache by default bind with current session by hibernate implicitly.

**Make below changes**:

```
Employee emp = (Employee) sf.getCurrentSession().get(Employee.class, 1l);
        System.out.println(emp.getName()); // Displays employee name

        System.out.println("DB Fetch Count : "+sf.getCurrentSession().getStatistics().getEntityCount());//Displays '1'!
```